# Creating unique txt files on android device every day, like a diary

Tags: android, file, sqlite, save

I am trying to create a diary for diabetics. The user will type in what they ate, how much, date they ate it and other comments. This is to be used when they go to their doctor and consult with them. So I need to make an app that takes the text from textfields, number from a numbers field and the date from a date field and store it in a .txt file. This .txt file I will try to upload to Google Drive later on. To prevent the .txt file to become to long/big, I was thinking I need to create a new .txt file every day or at least every week.

I have two questions :

1. Any suggestions how to create a new .txt every day/week?
2. Should I use SharePrefs or SQLLite for this?

I would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction. :)

Comment: `2013-09-16-stuff.txt`? SQLite would work fine, SharedPrefs not so much.

Comment: Yeah, but can I get the todays date and put it in as txt filename?

Comment: SQLite is the better solution for what you're trying to do. Forget about managing a ton of little plain text files and start developing a schema for your diary database.

Comment: Can I upload this to Google Drive or any other cloud to be printed out?